# Tools to generate Access Tokens for Devices without the use of platforms

Tags: security, voice-recognition

According to the present IoT landscape the Users of the data can either use the following interfaces to access IoT information:

- Web Apps
- Smart Phone Apps

However with the user of new technologies as interfaces like :

- AR/ VR
- Digital Voice Assistants

the data can be obtained from the respective devices and then utilized by the User.

The question is:

> How does one register these AR/VR and Digital Voice Assistants since they themselves do not have e-mail addresses and passwords that can be used to generate Access Tokens to query different APIs in the cloud infrastructure?

What are some security token generation tools for these devices and what is the token generation based on? Is the token completely random or is it based on some information like hardware IDs of such devices?

Comment: Apps or devices usually don't have e-mail addresses or passwords, it's their users who have them. The same applies for the web, phones, AR/VR devices, digital voice assistants. What you probably mean is more that there may not be a regular oAuth authentication/authorisation flow due to lack of a relevant input? All those devices are usually paired in some way with a device that can do that. Also, many APIs have separate auth flows for user interactions and server-to-server interaction for instance. You would probably need to be more specific about your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called oAuth.

It's a standard for issuing authentication tokens authorising services to act on behalf of users in a controlled way.